# Error: Invalid grouping factor specification

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I am trying to use `glmer` to model coral recruitment and get the error "Error: Invalid grouping factor specification, Site" when I run the model after re-scaling the variables. Help greatly appreciated

```
m1<-glmer(Tot~cs.Tile(Tile)+cs.Coral_T(Coral_T)+cs.Sponge(Sponge)+
cs.Turf(Turf)+cs.Acro(Acro)+cs.Por(Por)+cs.Poc(Poc)+
cs.Mer(Mer)+cs.Agar(Agar)+cs.Fav(Fav)+
cs.Den(Den)+cs.Sid(Sid)+cs.CCA(CCA)+cs.Soft(Soft)+
  (1|Site), 
family=poisson, data=data)
```

I have 16 variables and 368 obs:

```
str(data)
'data.frame':   368 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ Site   : Factor w/ 25 levels "Eight","Eighteen",..: 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
 $ Tile   : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Tot    : int  28 24 17 13 29 19 6 13 14 4 ...
 $ Coral_T: num  32.6 32.6 32.6 32.6 32.6 ...
 $ Sponge : num  0.206 0.206 0.206 0.206 0.206 ...
 $ Turf   : num  32.3 32.3 32.3 32.3 32.3 ...
 $ Acro   : num  3.45 3.45 3.45 3.45 3.45 ...
 $ Por    : num  1.15 1.15 1.15 1.15 1.15 ...
 $ Poc    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Mer    : num  0.175 0.175 0.175 0.175 0.175 0.175 0.175 0.175 0.175 0.175 ...
 $ Agar   : num  24.2 24.2 24.2 24.2 24.2 ...
 $ Fav    : num  1.02 1.02 1.02 1.02 1.02 ...
 $ Den    : num  1.18 1.18 1.18 1.18 1.18 ...
 $ Sid    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ CCA    : num  0.07 0.07 0.07 0.07 0.07 0.07 0.07 0.07 0.07 0.07 ...
 $ Soft   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Comment: can you explain your notation?  are the parentheses referring to alternative variables, e.g. you're either using `Tile` or `cs.Tile`, where the latter is the centered and scaled version of `Tile`?  I can't immediately see how this could happen.  Can we see what the centered-scaled data frame has in it?  I could guess that maybe you forgot to include `Site` in the centered-scaled data frame ... ???

Comment: alternately (and preferably) you could provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 11):

I encountered the same error in a call to `update.merMod`, also after re-scaling variables. After digging down through the `traceback()` stack and rummaging around with what I found there using both the scaled and un-scaled datasets, I found that the issue arose in the creation of the model frame, and occurred because my scaling and centering algorithm failed to account for `NA` values in the original variables. I originally performed the centering/scaling as follows:

```
csData <- data %>% mutate(Var1 = (Var1 - mean(Var1) / sd(Var1),
                          Var2 = (Var2 - mean(Var2) / sd(Var2))
```

There were a few `NA` values in one of those variables, and scaling and centering it in this way resulted in an empty (all `NA`) vector in `csData`. This subsequently (and silently) led to the return of an empty frame from `model.frame()`. Though the empty frame was what tripped the error, it (the error) came about because of my (mis)handling the `NA` values in my variables during the re-scaling. Setting `na.rm=TRUE` for the calls to `sd()` and `mean()` solved the issue for me:

```
csData <- data %>% mutate(Var1 = (Var1 - mean(Var1, na.rm=TRUE) / sd(Var1, na.rm=TRUE),
                          Var2 = (Var2 - mean(Var2, na.rm=TRUE) / sd(Var2, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Comment: Also answers my problem.  I scaled my continuous predictors, not realising that one column had some NAs.

Comment: I received the same error using `glmmTMB` for the same reason, some `NAs` had crept in to my data.